# How to view another data in the same column using webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I have 3 columns in my table, there are:
ID, Name, ParentDepartment

The value of ParentDepartment is an ID from column ID. For Example :

```
ID : 1,2,3

Name : Finance, Product and Services, IT Support

ParentDepartment : 1, 2, 2
```

It means the ID 1 has parent Department 'Finance', ID 2 & 3 has parent Department 'Product and Services'.

My question is how to show the Department name based on ParentDepartment in `WebGrid` column? So the result will be:

```
ID : 1, 2, 3

Name :  Finance, Product and Services, IT Support

ParentDepartment : Finance, Product and Services, Product and Services
```

Please your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inner join` to get such results.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name as Name, t2.Name AS ParentDepartment 
FROM myTable t1
INNER JOIN myTable t2
ON t1.ParentDepartment = t2.ID
```

However, it is very strange that `Finance` department's parent department is `Finance` department.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle Snippet](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2700/3/0).

Comment: How to use that in WebGrid?

Comment: @SunlikeSiagian My bad :( I've thought it is an SQL question. I will edit my question to answer your question or remove it in short.

Comment: Thankyou Yeldar. I understand that sql inner join, but i want to use that in 'WebGrid'.

here is my code:

grid.Column("Parent Department", "????"));

???? => I dont know how to join them in 'WebGrid'